# Synchronice a DataGrid with a list by a Thread (backgroundWorker). WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, datagrid

I´m tring to link data from a List to a DataGrid, but when I start the object BackgroundWorker, the main thread has been loaded (with a empty List) before the BackgroundWorker fill the List.
How can update or something in order to load the data from the BackgroundWorker ?

Constructor of MainWindow, here I declare the BackgroundWorker

````
```
  public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();            
    }
````

A methot to call the function backgroundWorker_DoWork

````
```       
  private void referenceBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {
        backgroundWorker.DoWork += backgroundWorker_DoWork;
        backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();

    }
````

If the operation is correct I get a lis of object(ApiProduct) and i save them.
I try to link by this method, but it´s static.
```

````
  public static void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        if (textinPut != null && textinPut.Length >= 3)
        {
            ApiConector apiConector = new ApiConector();
            UpdatedListProducts = apiConector.getProductList(textinPut, 2);
            //dgProducto.ItemsSource = UpdatedListProducts;
        }
    } 

```

 public static List<ApiProduct> UpdatedListProducts
    {
        get { return apiProductsStatic.ToList(); }
        set
        {
            apiProductsStatic = value;
        }
    } 

```

 <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,20,0,0"  Width="Auto">
                <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"  x:Name="dgProducto" CanUserAddRows="False" 
                    ColumnWidth="Auto" IsReadOnly="True" 
                          SelectedCellsChanged="dgProducto_SelectedCellsChanged"
                          EnableColumnVirtualization = "True" EnableRowVirtualization = "True"  
                         ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll ="False" DataGrid.RowHeight ="75" 
                           VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="auto"
                         >
                    <DataGrid.Columns  >
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="IMAGEN">
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Height="40" Width="40" 
                                     VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn >
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="NOMBRE" Binding="{Binding NameWhole}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="REFERENCIA" Binding="{Binding Reference}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="UBICACION" Binding="{Binding Location}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="PRECIO" Binding="{Binding Price}" />
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="">
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <Button x:Name="imprimirBtn" Content="Imprimir" 
                                        Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                        Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}" 
                                               Click="imprimirBtn_Click"  />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
            </Grid>
````

Comment: Then why you have made the method `backgroundWorker_DoWork` static? Remove `static`..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any need for static members, every window should have its own Data, and its own event handlers, so you should make them non-static

`UpdatedListProducts` from name show that the list is regularly in change so is better to make it of type `ObservableCollection<ApiProduct>` instead of `List<ApiProduct>` to notify the UI if items add or deleted and reflect that change in UI

here is a good article on [how to make UI Responding to changes](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/responding-to-changes/) with an intro to The ObservableCollection and the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Comment: Thanks, I change List<ApProduct> to ObservableCollection<ApiProduct> and I remove static sentences. Also I have used Dispatcher.Invoke for work with the main thread and it functions well.